# Size of popup does not match up with its content

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

In an extension I made for Chrome, I have defined the width and height of the popup to be `600 x 300 px`. It works perfectly fine before until Chrome recently updated to Chrome 27.

[image]

From the image screenshot above, you can see that I have set the width and height through CSS, but it still shows a 30 px gap in the bottom of the popup. This is frustrating because no matter what I tried the gap is still showing up. There is nothing floating outside the page, and I have also set `body` to `overflow: hidden`.

```
window.resize( /* */ );  //won't do anything different
```

So how can I make its size to be exactly `600 x 300` (in Chrome 27)?

Answer (score 0):

Try using background-size property like `background-size:100% 100%;` for its parent element which has that background.

Comment: It doesn't make any difference.